# escaping literal's in java string using regex

Tags: java, regex

i have a string value that i have to insert in mysql database. and i have to escape some literal like (' , " ,% ,) in this string so how can i use regex for that

Answer (score 8):

Don't use regex. Use a database library that escapes things for you, and let it handle this.

Comment: For instance... any JDBC driver with PreparedStatement or PreparedCall.

Comment: so how can we use database library? and what i have done this thing before through perl using regex but now i want that thing in java before inserting record in database

Comment: @lakhaman: Use prepared statements, and bind your (plain) string value as a parameter.  Simple, and orders of magnitude more likely to be correct than trying to roll your own regex.  See Jesper's answer for an example.

Comment: Use the PreparedStatement class, the documentation is here:
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to do this yourself. Let the JDBC driver handle it, by using `PreparedStatement` instead of concatenating an SQL statement using strings yourself. Example:

```
Connection conn = ...;    // Database connection

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MYTABLE (NAME, AGE) VALUES (?, ?)");

ps.setString(1, "Jesper");
ps.setInt(2, 38);

ps.executeUpdate();
```

If you use `PreparedStatement`, the JDBC driver will take care of escaping the inserted values correctly for whatever brand and version of the database that you use.